# Kernel approximation with Nystroem method and usage in scikit-learn

Tags: regression, gaussian-process, kernel-trick, approximation, rbf-kernel

I am planning to use the Nystroem method to approximate a Gram matrix induced by any kernel function. I found the Nystroem implementation in [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html).

As far as I understood, the full Gram Matrix should be estimated. Let have $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ as data points where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for all $i = 1 \ldots n$. My goal is to build a Kernel Matrix containing each pair $k(x_i, x_j)$. Then the output should be $\tilde{G} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}.$ The scikit-learn implementation, however, returns $\tilde{G} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ where $m$ is the number of components the user has given for the lower-rank approximation.

How can the full Gram/Kernel Matrix be approximated using scikit-learn?

```py
# imports
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import Nystroem
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF
    
# creating data
x = np.random.normal(size=(100, 2))

# accurate kernel function
kernel = RBF()
gram_matrix = kernel(x)
    
# approximated kernel function
m = 50
kernel_approx = Nystroem(kernel, n_components=m)
gram_matrix_approx = kernel_approx.fit_transform(x)
    
if gram_matrix.shape == gram_matrix_approx.shape:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

The shapes are always different. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Sklearn's `Nystroem` does not compute the Gram matrix itself, it returns the *Feature map* $\Phi$. The exact kernel matrix is approximated by $\tilde{G} = \Phi \Phi^\top$. Your code should look like this:

```py
kernel_approx = Nystroem(kernel, n_components=m)
feature_matrix = kernel_approx.fit_transform(x)
gram_matrix_approx = feature_matrix @ feature_matrix.T
```

And then

```py
if gram_matrix.shape == gram_matrix_approx.shape:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

would print what you expect.

You can check how good an approximation you got by visually comparing

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(gram_matrix)
plt.matshow(gram_matrix_approx)
plt.show()
```

If you do want the $n \times n$ Gram matrix, it will take $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ time if you compute it directly, and $\mathcal{O}(n^2 m)$ time if you first compute the Nystroem approximation and *then* evaluate $\Phi \Phi^\top$, so computing it directly would be faster.

Comment: I have actually implemented the Nystroem Method by myself now. It is marginally faster than computing it directly. As I understood, the singular value decomposition which was done by scikit-learn is not necessary and only needed for the proof or not?

And if the approximation has a worse running time complexity (by your statement), why is it used anyways?

Comment: When you actually want to apply it in kernel methods, the low-rank approximation $\Phi \Phi^\top$ can significantly speed up computation - details depend on the algorithm, but you never compute the product $\Phi \Phi^\top$ directly, instead you compute matrix-vector products $\Phi (\Phi^\top v)$.

Comment: @ManhKhôiDuong did my answer actually answer your question? if so it'd be nice if you could accept it, if not I'd be happy to clarify, just let me know! :)